# Is there any way for a level 17 Rogue to become an Oni?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rogue

I have a character who is a level 17 Rogue (any Roguish Archetype) that needs to be an [Oni](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/oni). The only solution I can find is using [*magic jar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar) while the Oni is in humanoid form:

> ***Change Shape.*** The oni magically polymorphs into a Small or Medium humanoid...

Is this possible within official rules? I'm stumped because the [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) doesn't work with 6th level spells.

Comment: Do you need to cast this once or often? And what is your subclass?

Comment: @NautArch just once is fine. And undecided thus far

Comment: As two answers have included a specific subclass, that may sway you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## As an Arcane Trickster, cast from a scroll.

See: [can an arcane trickster use a spell scroll from the wizard spell list?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73138/can-an-arcane-trickster-use-a-spell-scroll-from-the-wizard-spell-list)

There is a DC check involved in casting a spell above your capability.

[On using spell scrolls](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spell%20Scroll#content):

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your Spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a failed check, the spell disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

Comment: @BenBarden Guaranteed? Not by any means.  However, there are a few ways a character could get advantage on the roll.

Comment: @BenBarden Why do you think they don't have access to the Wizard Spell List. It only says: **When you reach 3rd level, you gain the ability to cast spells. See Spells Rules for the general rules of spellcasting and the Spells Listing for the wizard spell list.**

Comment: Well, we have a Crawford tweet now, so the matter is settled regardless.  I've removed my comments.

Comment: Interesting point, related to this post: Search out a Divination Wizard, ask them for good luck, and have them force the roll to be a success using Portent.

Answer (score 11):

## As a Thief, use a scroll via Use Magic Device

Use Magic Device allows a (13th-level or higher) [Thief Rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#Thief) to use magical items regardless of class, level, or race restrictions. Considering that a [spell scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) is defined as being unintelligible if it's not on your class list, a Thief should technically be able to use it.

Now, casting the spell from it is a little harder, as it requires an "ability check with [their] spellcasting ability", with a DC equaling 10 + the spell's level. Per DMG p. 141, a thief rogue's spellcasting ability modifier is +0, so it would simply be a d20 roll with no modifiers; to use a *magic jar* spell scroll, that's a DC 16 check with no bonuses (a 25% chance of success).

Considering a Thief has no magical talents, that's still pretty cool.

[For more info about using spell scrolls as a Thief Rogue, see this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89098/how-can-a-rogue-use-use-magic-device-to-cast-spells-from-scrolls).

Comment: That's a clever find.

Comment: It says, "you ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items." Not that you count as every class. The scroll requires a class spell list, which is not covered by Use Magic Device.

Comment: @DavidCoffron There is a quote on the link I posted that actually addresses this exact concern, potentially on page 141 of the DMG in the Casting Spells section.  I don't have it on me any time soon, so I can't prove that quote, but you can check it yourself. "If you don't have a spellcasting ability—perhaps you're a rogue with the Use Magic Device feature—your spellcasting ability modifier is +0 for the item[...]"  Once again, this is simply a quote someone else posted, so I have no actual idea if it's real or not.

Comment: Ita a real quote by i think it doesn't apply here (it's a reference to any spell cast from a magic object). I'll address in the linked question

Comment: Assuming my post is valid, I suppose you could find a Divination Wizard and pay them to use their Portent power to fudge the dice in your favor.

Comment: A little Guidance from a Cleric wouldn't hurt, either :)

Answer (score 10):

## At least two ways.

- True Polymorph (plus an hour of concentration) from a friendly caster ought to do the trick just fine.  As a 17th level rogue it's at least plausible that you're friends with someone capable of casting that.
- Magic Jar is on the wizard spell list.  The Arcane Trickster uses the Wizard spell list as the source for its spells.  [Crawford has stated that Arcane Tricksters (and Eldritch Knights) can, in fact, use higher-level wizard spells from scrolls.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/537374983576498176)  You'll have to roll (16-intmod) or better or waste the scroll and have to try again, but at that level, you should be able to afford a fair number of 6th-level spell scrolls.

Comment: For reference about the second option, [Crawford addresses this here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/537374983576498176): "The intent is yes, the Arcane Trickster and the Eldritch Knight can use scrolls with wizard spells on them."